# ArrayList only get the last item

Tags: java, arraylist

This is how I pass my item to the array and trying to loop it, but why I'm only get the last item in my array? Following is my code, kindly advise, thanks.

```
final GridView condimentGrid = (GridView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.condimentGrid);
                        CondimentList = getCondimentDescription(pCode);
                        condimentGrid.setAdapter(new condimentlist());

                        condimentGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                condimentItem = ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.condimentItem)).getText().toString();
                                String CondimentStatus = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.condimentStatus)).getText().toString();

                                data = new ArrayList<String>();
                                data.add(condimentItem);


                        }
                    });

                    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                          // array[] only get my last item that i Click
                          String array[] = data.toArray(new String[0]); 
                            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: `data = new ArrayList<String>();` is going to overwrite the list to a new empty list every time.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the initialization of the ArrayList out of the onclick listener as each time you click the array is initialized and all the previous data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Because on each item click you create new `ArrayList data`.
Check if it is null and then instantiate it:

```
 @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                condimentItem = ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.condimentItem)).getText().toString();
                                String CondimentStatus = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.condimentStatus)).getText().toString();

if(data==null)
       data = new ArrayList<String>();
       data.add(condimentItem);


                        }
```